# Deploying project with Kubernetes (Azure-AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, azure-aks

I am doing a project for my studies. I am supposed to create and deploy an app and I have decided to do this with AKS (because we have some prepaid credits there). I can run my deployments locally using Minikube, but I am not able to deploy it to AKS. Can you help me?

These are my deployment files:
app-ns.yml (for creating a namespace):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: pm
```

ab.yml (for deploying database):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db
  labels:
    app: pm-proc
    tier: database
  namespace: pm
spec:
  serviceName: postgresql-db-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgresql-db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgresql-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql-db
          image: postgres:15
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgresql-db-disk
              mountPath: /data
          env:
            - name: POSTGRESS_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: postgres
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: postgres
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /data/pgdata
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgresql-db-disk
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-db-svc
  namespace: pm
spec:
  selector:
    component: postgresql-db
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

api.yml (for deploying backend):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deploy
  labels:
    app: pm-proc
    tier: backend
    component: api
  namespace: pm
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pm-proc
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pm-proc
        tier: backend
        component: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: madzlk/backend-api:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DB_SERVICE_HOST
              value: $(POSTGRES_DB_SVC_SERVICE_HOST)
            - name: DB_SERVICE_PORT
              value: "5432"
            - name: DB_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: "postgres"
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: "postgres"
  replicas: 2

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc
  namespace: pm
spec:
  selector:
    app: pm-proc
    tier: backend
    component: api
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

api-np-svc.yml (creating a service to make API accessible externally):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-np-svc
  namespace: pm
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: pm-proc
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
```

This is just the API side. When everything is setup properly it is supposed to show an empty list

I have changed pods of type NodePort to Loadbalancer, because I have read that it is the way prefered by AKS, but it did not help.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  Is it a programming-related problem, or something around setting up the AKS deployment environment?

Comment: I think it is related to setting up the AKS deployment.  When i changed the service type in api-np-svc.yml to LoadBalancer and get rid of teh nodePort. Kubernetes generated the external ip address, but when i tried to access it on the 8080 port. I just saw that i cannot connect to tgis website (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your YAML as below to deploy Postgre on AKS

***PVC***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: pvc-postgre
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
storageClassName: managed-premium
resources:
requests:
storage: 1Gi
```

***Deployment***

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgresdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgresdb
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgresuser
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: postgrespwd
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: postgresdb
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/backup
        volumeMounts:
        - name: database
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          subPath: backup
      volumes:
      - name: database
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-postgre
```

Apply the same using.

```
kubectl apply -f <the-yaml-file-name>
```

Now do `kubectl get pods | grep post`

***output***
[image]

Now you can connect to the database using

```
kubectl exec -it <your-postgresdb-pod-name> --psql -h localhost -U <the_username_which_you_kept_in_the_yaml> --password -p 5432 postgresdb
```

***output***
[image]
[image]

you can expose the pod through a load balancer type service by using below yaml

***Service***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-db-lb
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgresdb
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 5432
```

Apply the same using
`kubectl apply -f <service-yaml-file-name>`
Now do `kubectl get svc | grep postgres-db-lb`  #note, this will be whatever name you kept inside the service yaml
***output***
[image]

You can now use this LB IP to connect to the [pgadmin UI tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/)

[image]

Reference document:

[GitHub_PostgresOnAKS](https://github.com/patpishiva/AKS/blob/main/postgresdb.yml)

[Deploying PostgreSQL as a StatefulSet](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/kubernetes-postgresql/)